# How to scale shape without moving the connecting point

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to resize the small petals shapes to fit into the bigger petals without moving the tip of the small petals.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Use scale tool and Alt click on the point you want to be your base point

Answer (score 1):

If you draw the small petals as straight line segments, you can scale them easily visually (no numbers) without changing the other endpoint. Apply a custom art brush to them, they scale still as line segments:

[image]

1. Line segments are placed
2. An art brush is applied. I have also a reversed copy because half of the lines are reversed due the not so clever making of them (=rotated long lines are splitted with Pathfinder panel outline)
3. Scaled individually - unfortunately it must be done by eye and the stroke width scale too. Brush option "stretch to fit stroke length" prevent thinning. I had proportional scaling.
4. The petals in the comb are selected. Object > Expand Appearance is applied. The petals are now normal paths and can be edited freely. I gave to them same stroke width 0,5 mm. See the Cap and Corner options. Round ends and corners reduce clutter in the common point of the sharp ends.